# NSArray crashes app when it has more than 2 objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsnotificationcenter

so I've been working with `NSNotificationCenter` in Xcode and I've tried to attach a `NSDictionary` to my notification using `userInfo`.

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Example Name", @"Example Description", @"Example Date", nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"description", @"date", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary 
                               dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                               forKeys:keys];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

When I try to run the app and post the notification, it crashes at the line:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"description", @"date", nil];
```

I later found that if the array size exceeded 2 objects, the app would crash.

So if I changed my code to the snippet below, it would work.

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Example Name", @"Example Description", nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"description", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary 
                                   dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                   forKeys:keys];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

Is there any way I can work around this, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Do you have ARC enabled? Btw you are missing a bracket before posting the notification, it's just a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: It should work - are you sure the objects you are using are valid?

Comment: The example uses string liberals so they should be valid objects. When you're getting a crash, are you getting an exception? Or EXC_BAD_ACCESS? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: ah. I hate when this happens.. Xcode was actin up again. I restarted my computer and it worked. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Does this code compile? Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: it does. like I said, it works when I remove the third object from each array

Comment: Close XCode and restart it. That's voodoo.

Comment: And if you're down voting this. Let me know why. It's free.

Comment: Yeah, the advice was actually valid.